# Global section and Smooth vector fields

Tags: smooth-manifolds

For a given smooth bundle, a global section may or may not be available. As I understood smooth vector field (not a local smooth vector field) is a global section of the tangent bundle.

How do we know such a global section exists for a given tangent bundle?

Also, if we have a smooth vector field defined does it mean the bundle is trivial?

Thanks

Comment: You always have the zero section.

Comment: Thanks. Also, could you describe what happens if the smooth manifold is a Lie group? Do Lie groups always have smooth sections, so that the tangent bundle is trivial?

Comment: Indeed, Lie groups are even parallelizable: a Lie group of dimension $n$ has $n$ global vector fields that are at each point linearly independent. They are obtained by doing translations in the group — you will find a construction in pretty much every introductory textbook (for example, Lee's)

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot.